# String formatting, how to give equal width to 'iiii' and 'wwww'

Tags: java, string, formatting

I want to make the output of JConsole to similar of a table.
I concatenate some Strings to form 'rows'. In order to resemble a real table the (sub)Strings that form the row should have equal physical length.

Something like this:

```
aaa aaa aaa
bbb bbb bbb
ccc ccc ccc
```

I use the following method to set the length of the String.

```
private String fillWithSpace(String s){
            if(s == null){
                s = " null                    ";
            }
            while(s.length()<CONSTANT_LENGTH){
                s = s + " ";
            }       
            return s;
        }
```

But it does not help me if the letters have significantly different width.
Is there a clever way to give ***iii*** and ***www*** the same **physical** width?

Comment: Why not just pick a fixed width font, if you want fixed width characters?

Comment: I am not familiar with JConsole, but if it uses the same type of graphics as JComponents then you should be able to choose a Font. Select family as Courier or Monospaced and this should do it automatically

Comment: JConsole is not JComponents, but a performance monitoring tool. I am highly doubtful that it can support Font..

Answer (score 1):

You should use monospaced font.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with JConsole?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with JConsole.